# Keycloak - Is it possible to map composite roles and their attributes to the access token?

Tags: java, keycloak

What I am trying to accomplish is a way to map the composite roles(and their attributes), as well as their "child" roles to the access token in order to use that data.

I only see the user attribute mapper in keycloak admin console but for the role attribute I see none. Also, how do we maintain the structure/granularity of the composite roles, in order to check which roles they have aggregated?

The main idea is to have something like this:

*User -> (Composite Roles with several attributes -> Roles)*

I have also tried to get the information that I need this way but without success, as it throws an http `403 Forbidden exception` when trying to get the `realmResource.toRepresentation`.

What I was doing:

```
String keycloakRealm = tenantContext.getOrganizationRequestConfig().getKeycloakRealm();
RealmResource realmResource = keycloak().realm(keycloakRealm);

if (realmResource != null) {
    List<RoleRepresentation> rolesRepresentationList= realmResource.toRepresentation().getRoles().getRealm();
    for (RoleRepresentation rolesRepresentation : rolesRepresentationList) {
        Composites composites = rolesRepresentation.getComposites();
        Map<String, List<String>> attributes = rolesRepresentation.getAttributes();
    }
}
```

If is not possible to do using this approach ( User -> (Composite Roles with several attributes -> Roles) ), do you guys have any suggestion or alternative approach?

The ideia is to map this into the access token, but I am finding it difficult to have this structure in place in the token

Thanks

*Note: I need to integrate with Azure AD*

Edit: Client protocol is OIDC

Comment: Did you try to use builtin mapper types `User Realm Role`,`User Client Role` or user federation mapper `role-ldap-mapper`?

Comment: Hi Jan,

I have used both Realm Role and Client Role Mappers but the structure is not maintained, the composite roles and the roles are in the same level of the tree in the access token.
Also, the user attribute mapper don't map the role composite attributes that I have in place

Comment: Have you tried writing your custom attribute mapper ?